# Need to prevent parsing a huge CSV file repeatedly in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I have a huge a CSV file which I parse to store the data in a PHP array. For different PHP files I have to parse it again and again to store it in the array. How can I prevent this by storing it in array and then have this array available to all PHP files?

Comment: @SLaks, That doesn't really help him, because while it would certainly speed up access time, he still has to make many requests. His actual problem is that he doesn't know how to store the result globally so that all his PHP classes/files have access to the already parsed data.

Comment: @SLaks - Yes.  Thank you.  @ kurtzbot - Which is probably poor design.  Storing the result globally only makes sense if you're running a bunch of jobs on the data at once.  But if they're not sequential, then the data can't be shared.

Comment: I think @SLaks is completely right. It reads as if the OP is using CSV files as a poor mans DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apc_cache()` is what you want. http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

You can write it to a file. Use serialize() before. Then include the file each time you need it (include_once):

```
$my_csv_data = serialize($data);
```

Comment: CSV files aren't particularly hard to parse; his parsing time might be dominated by disk I/O.   If that's the case, how will this help? It converts reading one kind of file, into writing/reading another kind of file.

Comment: while this *technically* is a solution because it prevents having to reparse the file as csv, it still gets reparsed by each php script when they calls unserialize(), and so isn't significantly better.

Comment: But you need include file once, then will be available in memory for all process...

Comment: @NomikOS The same is true for the csv file - load it once and it's in memory. You still have to parse the PHP file, just like you parse the CVS file. There is no net gain.

Comment: What user wants is avoid `parse it again and again to store it in the array`. So I propose save the array to a file. The process to avoid is repeatedly transform cvs data to a variable.

Comment: Writing to disk will end up costing way more cycles than reparsing the file. What I would do is actually gzcompress the CSV file to speed up retrieval.

Comment: You only need write the file once. The array will be available for ever until cvs data changes and needs a new file update. Don't forget that user said: `How can I prevent this by storing it in array and then have this array available to all PHP files?`

Comment: Hell, if you're going to do that, you might as well save the array to a PHP file and include it. Then there's a chance that a opcode cache might give you a boost.

Answer (score 0):

Store the array in a file using [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/funciton.serialize.php):

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', serialize($data));
```

Then when you need to access it again, use [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/funciton.unserialize.php):

```
$data = unserialize(file_get_contents('file.txt'));
```